# Как загрузить проект в Storm целиком?

Tags: phpstorm

Скачал я всю структуру папок, файлов с сервера, как это всё целиком закинуть в один проект PHPStorm?

Comment: File->New project... Там выбираешь папку и все. К.О.

Comment: File->New project, выбираете корневую папку и соглашаетесь создать проект на основе существующих файлов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File->New Project From Existing Files...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбрать Web server is on remote host, files are accessible via FTP/SFTP/FTPS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задать имя проекта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбрать Add New remote server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ввести параметры ftp-сервера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбрать корень проекта (и папки, которые надо исключить из загрузки или индексации).

Отвечать на последний вопрос о webpath не обязательно, можно оставить поле пустым.

Проект готов к работе.